# why mysql_query (SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE ) get null value of auto_increment value

Tags: php, auto-increment

The Table's definition is as:

```
CREATE TABLE `oc_product_option_value` (
      `product_option_value_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `product_option_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `option_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `option_value_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
       ...
)
```

The PHP code is as:

```
...
$res = mysql_query("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE '%product_option_value'");
//$res = mysq_query("SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'product_option_value'");

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

$n_id = is_null( $row['Auto_increment']) ? 'null' : $row['Auto_increment'] ;

...
```

Well, I always get a null value?

Comment: from where are you running the code? perhaps you have no privileges or is forbidden by server?

Comment: What does `var_dump($row)` give you, and what result are you getting with the exact same query run over a frontend like phpMyAdmin or similar?